# Binding value to child scope in angular js

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that creates a row in a table. I then use ng-repeat to iterate over a list of items to populate the table with the directive row, e.g.:

```
<tr ng-repeat='item in items' rowItem='item' />
```

I am having a problem defining the scope.
I can't use `scope: false` because that does not separate the rowItem values.
I want to be able to bind to the rowItem value so using an isolated scope: `scope:{rowItem: '='}` which works as I want, but I still want the parent scope values to be accessible.

So the best choice would be `scope: true` however, I can't bind the scope to the row item.
I tried using `attrs.$observe('rowItem', ...)` but this does not fire when the list of items changes because the rowItem is not an interpolated attribute.

Is there a way to use a new child scope (`scope: true`) that can bind to an attribute (like it does in the isolated scope)?

Comment: `You observer like this scope.watch(attrs.rowItem,function)`

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that but that works the same as attrs.$observe and only updates when the attribute value changes rather than the interpolated value changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Gd3t/4/) to try to replicate the issue but it appears the child scope (`scope: true`) is updating as regularly as the isolated scope. I must have another issue that is causing $observe not to fire as regularly.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a [working CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kvorw) that should give you the answer you are looking for.

The trick is using the scope.$eval(...) as I demonstrate in my example. I also want to point out that it seems you may be trying to misuse directives a little bit, but without knowing more about the exact requirements I am simply providing you an answer. You could probably complete your requirements without a custom directive based on the simplicity of the example you gave.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was using $eval as well but I thought the observe was not being triggered when the item was changing. I created a fiddle to try to recreate the issue but it turns out that $observe is called when the item changes, but for some reason it is not for me.

Answer (score 0):

`$observe` is not available in scope, it is available  in `attrs`:

```
link: function(scope, elements, attrs){
    attrs.$observe('rowItem', ...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that was just a typo.